# How to create a query in Drupal 8

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-8

I am used to using db_select in drupal 7 but now it's deprecated in drupal 8

So, If I need to create a query to list all users from `users_field_data` table, What should I do?

Do I still use `db_select` or `db_query` even though they are deprecated functions? Or create a new controller to extend from "`Select class`" and make my query?

Comment: I would recommend you to rephrase the question probably to something like "how to make a query in D8" because as is it attracts votes to close due to being opinion-based.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 20):

Depends on what you are trying to achieve.

---

#### Using the storage object

*If you want to make a simple query about the users then you should use the loadByProperties of the storage object*

```
$users = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')->loadByProperties([
  'name' => 'bar'
]);
```

---

#### Using entity query & loadMultiple

*If you need a more complex query with sorts, range, pager and OR/AND condition groups you should use entity query*

```
$ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('user')->condition('name', 'foo')->execute();
$users = User::loadMultiple($ids);
```

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned in the documentation you can query data by injecting Drupal's database connection class. For example:

```
use Drupal\Core\Database\Connection;

class DatabaseQueryExample {

  protected $connection;

  public function __construct(Connection $connection) {
    $this->connection = $connection;
  }

  public function queryExamples() {
    // db_query()
    $this->connection->query(" ... ");
    // db_select()
    $this->connection->select(" ... ");   
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this comment! It was very helpful!

Answer (score 10):

`db_select`, `db_insert`, `db_update`, etc... were deprecated in Drupal `8.0.x` and will be removed in Drupal `9.0.0`.

Instead get a database connection injected into your service from the container and call `select()` on it. For example, `$injected_database->select($table, $alias, $options);`.

eg:

```
$db = \Drupal::database();

$data = $db->select('table_name','t')->fields('t')->execute();

$db->insert();

$db->update();
```

Comment: Question: areboth instances of `'t'` the name of the rows you want to get?

Comment: fields() takes more than 1 parameter, if you use ->fields('t') i.e, you provide only 1 parameter, which is what you have defined as the alias, it translates to '*' that you would have used to fetch all fields in case you were writing an SQL query. to fetch a set of fields, say 'a', 'b' from the table you use ->fields('t', array('a', 'b'))